# Cordova App: put files in directory during installation

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file, fileopener2

in my app I would include an information section, then view the local pdf files.

For opening the file with the default app, I already use fileopener2 plugin, by downloading and placing into the appropriate folder, accessible from external app.

Otherwise, now the files are already local, I do not have to download them, and I would include them into apk.
How can I do that, during installation of the app, this pdf are copied directly in an accessible location, such as cordova.file.externalDataDirectory?